# Incorrect Typescript parameter

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to pass this TypeScript array to a function. I've tried a number of parameter types to make this compile, but none of them seem to work. Here's the array:

```
var driverTally = [
                    { driver: 'driver1', numEscorts: 0},
                    { driver: 'driver2', numEscorts: 0},
                    { driver: 'driver3', numEscorts: 0} 
                ];

doStuff(driverTally : Array<[string,number]>){ ... }
```

The compiler keeps saying : "Argument of type '{ driver: string; numEscorts: number; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[string, number][]'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cna use any if you are not sure about the type,

```
doStuff(driverTally : any){ ... }
```

or create a Class of the following type

```
export class Driver {
   public string driver;
   public int numEscorts;
}
```

and then declare your array as,

```
driverstally : Driver[] = [
                    { driver: 'driver1', numEscorts: 0},
                    { driver: 'driver2', numEscorts: 0},
                    { driver: 'driver3', numEscorts: 0} 
                ];
```

and then pass it as,

```
doStuff(driverTally :Driver[] ){ ... }
```

Comment: I made a Driver class. I guess I should have just done that right away, but it bugged me that I couldn't get the type right for the function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to determine interface:

```
interface IDriver {
    drive: string;
    numEscorts: number;
}
```

Then declare array with initialization:

```
public drivers: IDriver[] = [];
```

After you can pass this array as function parameter:

```
doStuff(driverTally: IDriver[] ){ ... }
```